# Sorting Array of structs in Solidity

Tags: arrays, sorting, struct, solidity

I've been looking online on how to implement a sorting function to my Array of structs in **Solidity**. I want to sort the candidate array of structs by field name "voteCount"

## my Struct looks like this:

```
`struct Candidate {
    uint candidateId;
    string CandidateName;
    string party;
    uint voteCount;
  }`
```

## my Array of structs:

```
`Candidate [] public registeredCandidates;`
```

I want to be able to return an array of structs in my function **returnResult** sorted by voteCount.

## my returnResult function:

```
`function sortCandidate() public view return(Candidate[] memory){
    //do stuff here to sort the array of struct by voteCount.
 }`
```

## returnCandidates function ( works fine)

```
 `function returnCandidates() public view returns (Candidate[] memory){
      Candidate[] memory array = new Candidate[](candidatesCount);
      for (uint i = 0; i < candidatesCount; i++) {
        Candidate storage candidate = registeredCandidates[i];
        array[i] = candidate;
      }
      return array;
   }`
```

Can someone please help me with an easy approach. Thank you in advance all.

Comment: like top-down list?

Comment: Yes sir, but i figured that I can do in my front end with javascript sort() function

Comment: Great, cause ive tried to implement it with solidity and kinda stuck. Well, good luck.